# No valid form to update in symfony - controller

Tags: forms, symfony, controller, fosuserbundle

So first of all i am using FOSUserBundle in Symfony2.1 and that stores my roles as an **longtext** in the usertable:

```
a:1:{i:0;s:14:"ROLE_SUPERUSER";}
```

I am able to retrieve the data and send it to a form in a twig bij this code in a controller:

```
public function editUserAction($userId) {
  $User = $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager')
    ->findUserBy(array('id' => $userId))
  ;

  $selectedRole = $User->getRoles();


  if($selectedRole[0] == 'ROLE_DISTRICTINHABITANT') {
      $selectedRoleNumber = 0;
  } elseif($selectedRole[0] == 'ROLE_DISTRICTWORKER') {
      $selectedRoleNumber = 1;
  } elseif($selectedRole[0] == 'ROLE_CITYWORKER') {
      $selectedRoleNumber = 2;
  } elseif($selectedRole[0] == 'ROLE_ADMIN') {
      $selectedRoleNumber = 3;
  } elseif($selectedRole[0] == 'ROLE_SUPERADMIN') {
      $selectedRoleNumber = 4;
  }      

  $form = $this->createFormBuilder($User)
      ->add('username', 'text')
      ->add('email', 'email')
      ->add('enabled', 'checkbox', array('required' => false))
      ->add('roles', 'choice', array(
          'choices' => array(
              0 => 'DistrictInhabitant',
              1 => 'DistrictWorker',
              2 => 'CityWorker',
              3 => 'Admin',
              4 => 'SuperAdmin',
          ),
          'data' => $selectedRoleNumber
      ))
  ->getForm();

  return $this->render('SocialGeoBackendBundle:Users:edit.html.twig', array(
      'form' => $form->createView(),
      'user' => $User,
  ));
}
```

But when i try to save this data to the database by another function, i don't get past:

```
if ($form->isValid())
```

here is my complete function that doesn't seem to work:

```
public function editUserToDatabaseAction($userId) {
    $request = $this->get('request');

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

    $User = $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager')
        ->findUserBy(array('id' => $userId))
    ;

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($User)
        ->add('username', 'text')
        ->add('email', 'email')
        ->add('enabled', 'checkbox')
        ->add('roles', 'choice', array(
            'choices' => array(
                'DistrictInhabitant' => 'DistrictInhabitant',
                'DistrictWorker' => 'DistrictWorker',
                'CityWorker' => 'CityWorker',
                'Admin' => 'Admin',
                'SuperAdmin' => 'SuperAdmin',
            )
        ))
        ->getForm();

    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
        $form->bind($this->getRequest());

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em->flush();
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('_users'));
        }
    }
}
```

entire controller class:

```
<?php

namespace SocialGeo\BackendBundle\Controller;

use SocialGeo\BackendBundle\Form;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use SocialGeo\UserBundle\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class UsersController extends Controller {

 public function indexAction() {
    $Users = $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager')
        ->findUsers()
    ; 

    if (!$Users) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('No users found!');
    }

    return $this->render('SocialGeoBackendBundle:Users:index.html.twig', array('users' => $Users));     
}

 public function changeActiveStateAction($id) {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $selectedUser = $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager')
        ->findUserBy(array('id' => $id));

    $active = $selectedUser->isEnabled();
    if($active) {
        $selectedUser->setEnabled(FALSE);
    } else {
        $selectedUser->setEnabled(TRUE);
    }

    $em->flush();

    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('_users'));
 }

 public function editUserAction($userId) {
    $User = $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager')
        ->findUserBy(array('id' => $userId))
    ;


    $selectedRole = $User->getRoles();


    if($selectedRole[0] == 'ROLE_DISTRICTINHABITANT') {
        $selectedRoleNumber = 0;
    } elseif($selectedRole[0] == 'ROLE_DISTRICTWORKER') {
        $selectedRoleNumber = 1;
    } elseif($selectedRole[0] == 'ROLE_CITYWORKER') {
        $selectedRoleNumber = 2;
    } elseif($selectedRole[0] == 'ROLE_ADMIN') {
        $selectedRoleNumber = 3;
    } elseif($selectedRole[0] == 'ROLE_SUPERADMIN') {
        $selectedRoleNumber = 4;
    }


    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($User)
        ->add('username', 'text')
        ->add('email', 'email')
        ->add('enabled', 'checkbox', array('required' => false))
        ->add('roles', 'choice', array(
            'choices' => array(
                0 => 'DistrictInhabitant',
                1 => 'DistrictWorker',
                2 => 'CityWorker',
                3 => 'Admin',
                4 => 'SuperAdmin',
            ),
            'data' => $selectedRoleNumber
        ))
        ->getForm();

    return $this->render('SocialGeoBackendBundle:Users:edit.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'user' => $User,
    ));
 }

 public function editUserToDatabaseAction($userId) {
    $request = $this->get('request');

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

    $User = $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager')
        ->findUserBy(array('id' => $userId))
    ;

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($User)
        ->add('username', 'text')
        ->add('email', 'email')
        ->add('enabled', 'checkbox')
        ->add('roles', 'choice', array(
            'choices' => array(
                'DistrictInhabitant' => 'DistrictInhabitant',
                'DistrictWorker' => 'DistrictWorker',
                'CityWorker' => 'CityWorker',
                'Admin' => 'Admin',
                'SuperAdmin' => 'SuperAdmin',
            ),
            'empty_value' => false, // user always has at least the default role
            'multiple' => true,
        ))
        ->getForm();

    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {

        $form->bind($this->getRequest());

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            print_r(jej);
            //$data = $form->getData();
            $em->flush();
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('_users'));
        }
    }
 }
}
```

So when i try the update, i get a Expected argument of type "array", "string" given
500 Internal Server Error - UnexpectedTypeException

when i try: print_r(xxx); i get the print command working anywhere above the if ($form->isValid()) so my form isn't valid?

Also: i am sure that createFormBuilder ->add('roles' ... throws the error because when i put this add in comment it works so... it's the fault of the array, how can i fix this in the controller?

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: What is the message you get why it failed?

Comment: the browser throws me a 500 internal server error, so no error in the log files

Comment: I ran your form builder code in a simple test with Symfony 2.1.3 and it didn't break for me. In fact, if your print_r() succeeds down to $form->isValid() then presumably that is the line it breaks on? I'd say the issue is something to do with the mapping between the User and form objects, the roles attribute seeming the likely candidate if removing it removes the error.

Comment: You're still missing the return statement at the end of the action method. If the form is submitted with invalid data your application will break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finnally I found a solution. Firstly, I set my `post` in the twig to the same route (to the same action in my controller). Then I used setters of `FOSUserBundle` when the post method is requested, finally an `updateUser` finished the job.

Here is my code of the single action in my controller:

```
public function editUserAction($userId) {
    $request = $this->get('request');

    $User = $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager')
        ->findUserBy(array('id' => $userId))
    ;

    $selectedRole = $User->getRoles();


    if($selectedRole[0] == 'ROLE_DISTRICTINHABITANT') {
        $selectedRoleNumber = 0;
    } elseif($selectedRole[0] == 'ROLE_DISTRICTWORKER') {
        $selectedRoleNumber = 1;
    } elseif($selectedRole[0] == 'ROLE_CITYWORKER') {
        $selectedRoleNumber = 2;
    } elseif($selectedRole[0] == 'ROLE_ADMIN') {
        $selectedRoleNumber = 3;
    } elseif($selectedRole[0] == 'ROLE_SUPERADMIN') {
        $selectedRoleNumber = 4;
    }


    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($User)
        ->add('username', 'text')
        ->add('email', 'email')
        ->add('enabled', 'checkbox', array('required' => false))
        ->add('roles', 'choice', array(
            'choices' => array(
                0 => 'DistrictInhabitant',
                1 => 'DistrictWorker',
                2 => 'CityWorker',
                3 => 'Admin',
                4 => 'SuperAdmin',
            ),
            'data' => $selectedRoleNumber
        ))
        ->getForm();

    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {


        $postData = $request->request->get('form');
        $roles_value = $postData['roles'];

        if($roles_value == 0) {
            $FutureRole[0] = "ROLE_DISTRICTINHABITANT";
        } else if($roles_value == 1) {
            $FutureRole[0] = "ROLE_DISTRICTWORKER";
        } else if($roles_value == 2) {
            $FutureRole[0] = "ROLE_CITYWORKER";
        } else if($roles_value == 3) {
            $FutureRole[0] = "ROLE_ADMIN";
        } else if($roles_value == 4) {
            $FutureRole[0] = "ROLE_SUPERADMIN";
        }

        $userManager = $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager');

        $selectedUser = $userManager->findUserBy(array('id' => $userId));

        $selectedUser->setUsername($postData['username']);
        $selectedUser->setEmail($postData['email']);
        $selectedUser->setEnabled($postData['enabled']);
        $selectedUser->setRoles($FutureRole);

        $userManager->updateUser($selectedUser, true);

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('_users'));

    } else {
        return $this->render('SocialGeoBackendBundle:Users:edit.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'user' => $User,
        ));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

EDITED FOLLOWING ADDITION OF FULL CONTROLLER CODE TO QUESTION:

Rather than attempting to diagnose a specific error, here is an example of an action for editing your FOS User with roles, covering both GET and POST (you only need a single route/action so you'll need to update your routing)

```
public function editUserAction($userId) {
    $user = $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager')
        ->findUserBy(array('id' => $userId));

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($user)
        ->add('username', 'text')
        ->add('email', 'email')
        ->add('enabled', 'checkbox')
        ->add('roles', 'choice', array(
            'choices' => array(
                'DistrictInhabitant' => 'DistrictInhabitant',
                'DistrictWorker' => 'DistrictWorker',
                'CityWorker' => 'CityWorker',
                'Admin' => 'Admin',
                'SuperAdmin' => 'SuperAdmin',
            ),
            'empty_value' => false, // user always has at least one role
            'multiple' => true,
        ))
        ->getForm();

    if ($this->getRequest()->getMethod() == 'POST') {

        $form->bind($this->getRequest());

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
            $em->flush();
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('_users'));
        }
    }

    return $this->render('SocialGeoBackendBundle:Users:edit.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'user' => $user,
        ));
}
```

I can't guarantee this is error free but hopefully it will be enough to help you towards a working version.

Comment: Also, whilst developing you need to run Symfony in the dev environment as it provides detailed info on errors that is hidden from the user in the production environment.

Comment: i didn't use the function extractRoles that you suggested but i did use your add roles method, I edited the question a bit. because it's the same mistake, just another error that gets displayed...
 the error I get now in development environment is this: Notice: Array to string conversion in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/SocialGeo/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/ChoiceList/ChoiceList.php line 457
500 Internal Server Error - ErrorException, so yea, is it possible just to adjust my controller instead of making a new method as your second block of code suggests?

Comment: Ok, I think I know why you're getting that error. I'll update my answer.

Comment: hmmm now i get still the error that Expected argument of type "array", "string" given
500 Internal Server Error - UnexpectedTypeException
again one step further, atleast now it doesn't try to converse the given string, but i did add all my roles into your '...'

Comment: also i deleted the default role that FOSUserBundle provides. they all have an role to begin with though. i really need to replace the existing role, not add one. Also where should i add this return? I already have a return in my 4th last line (check questing). Thanks already, i deleted some answers to keep this discussion clean.

Comment: Without a stack trace or some indication of where the next error is occurring it's impossible to diagnose it. It could be anything. Possibly somewhere you are setting a single string role into either a user or the form.

Comment: I believe I've answered your original issue and more. Please can you accept the answer. I don't mind remotely debugging your code but that isn't what SO is for and it would be more efficient if I had a copy of your code.

Comment: My problem isn't solved so accepting will close the thread, won't it? Wanne start up a new question and accept this one if you want? Want to send you my project, but i don't find your mail address. updated my question with full controller class...

Comment: Does the exception message tell you what class/method/line the exception is occurring in? What is happening on that line of code?

Comment: in ChoicesToValuesTransformer.php, it throws the exception from if (!is_array($array)) {
            throw new UnexpectedTypeException($array, 'array');
        }

Comment: Your two action methods do not build the form in the same way. In particular, the first form build does not set multiple=true for the roles choice field so the request will not contain an array value for the role field. You should be able to verify this by dumping the request. Even if you fix that, the fact that the first choice is keyed on integers and the second on role names will still cause you a problem. The forms used for submission and validation must be the same. This is why it is best practice to use custom form classes.

Comment: You should copy the return from the end of the first edit action to be the last statement of the second action. Alternatively you could combine the two methods. If I have time later I'll add an example to the answer but it won't be error free as I can't run it!